# JavaScript - sort to do list by date then status

Tags: javascript

I have a to do list that I need to sort by `dueDate` and by status (incomplete => complete). The incomplete tasks should be in ASC order by dueDate. Then the completed tasks should come after incomplete tasks and they should also be in ASC order by `dueDate`.

```
unsorted array 
[{"task":"Dishes", "isComplete":false, "dueDate":"2021-01-01T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"feed baby", "isComplete":true, "dueDate":"2021-01-02T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"Laundry", "isComplete":true, "dueDate":"2021-01-04T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"Homework", "isComplete":false, "dueDate":"2021-01-03T15:45:00.000Z"}]

sorted array
    [
    {
    "task":"Dishes",
    "isComplete":false,
    "dueDate":"2021-01-01T15:45:00.000Z"
    },
    {
    "task":"Homework",
    "isComplete":false,
    "dueDate":"2021-01-03T15:45:00.000Z"
    }
    {
    "task":"feed baby",
    "isComplete":true,
    "dueDate":"2021-01-02T15:45:00.000Z"
    },
    {
    "task":"Laundry",
    "isComplete":true,
    "dueDate":"2021-01-04T15:45:00.000Z"
    },
    ]
```

Here is my approach using 2 sort functions, first by date then by status but I feel it can be reduced further:

```
const sortByDate = (a,b) => {
    if (new Date(a.dueDate) < new Date(b.dueDate)){
        return -1;
    }
    if (new Date(a.dueDate) > new Date(b.dueDate)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
const sortByStatus = (a,b) => {
    if (a.isComplete < b.isComplete){
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.isComplete > b.isComplete) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the coercive property of subtraction and the logical OR operator.

```js
const arr = [{"task":"Dishes", "isComplete":false, "dueDate":"2021-01-01T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"feed baby", "isComplete":true, "dueDate":"2021-01-02T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"Laundry", "isComplete":true, "dueDate":"2021-01-04T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"Homework", "isComplete":false, "dueDate":"2021-01-03T15:45:00.000Z"}];
arr.sort((a,b) => a.isComplete - b.isComplete || new Date(a.dueDate) - new Date(b.dueDate));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Can you please tell what logical OR does in this case? Also isComplete is a boolean value then what minus will do between boolean values (a.isComplete - b.isComplete)?

Comment: @learner `true` will be coerced to `1` and `false` to `0` when subtracting. `||` will return the first truthy operand, so if the first comparison results in `0` (equal), it will use the result of the second comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for a combined sort function. Then this should do the work

```
const sortArray = (a,b) => {
    if (new Date(a.dueDate) < new Date(b.dueDate)){
        return -1;
    }
    else if (new Date(a.dueDate) > new Date(b.dueDate)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {  // This else means, due date is same, and we need to consider the status in this case
        if (b.isComplete){
            return 1;
        }
        else if (a.isComplete) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0; // This means status and due date are equal
    }
};
```

First this will sort by the due date. If the due dates are equal, then the status will be considered for such elements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
array.sort((a, b) => {
  return sortByStatus(a,b) || sortByDate(a, b);
});
```

### More descriptive

```js
array.sort((a, b) => {
  const byStatus = sortByStatus(a, b)
  // if status isn't same, compare by status
  if( byStatus !== 0 ) return byStatus;
  // else compare by date
  return sortByDate(a,b);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```js
unsorted_arr =
[{"task":"Dishes", "isComplete":false, "dueDate":"2021-01-01T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"feed baby", "isComplete":true, "dueDate":"2021-01-02T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"Laundry", "isComplete":true, "dueDate":"2021-01-04T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"Homework", "isComplete":false, "dueDate":"2021-01-03T15:45:00.000Z"}];

unsorted_arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    if(a.isComplete == b.isComplete)
        return (a.dueDate < b.dueDate) ? -1 : (a.dueDate > b.dueDate) ? 1 : 0;
    else
        return (a.isComplete < b.isComplete) ? -1 : 1;
});
console.log(unsorted_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```js
var array = [{"task":"Dishes", "isComplete":false, "dueDate":"2021-01-01T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"feed baby", "isComplete":true, "dueDate":"2021-01-02T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"Laundry", "isComplete":true, "dueDate":"2021-01-04T15:45:00.000Z"},{"task":"Homework", "isComplete":false, "dueDate":"2021-01-03T15:45:00.000Z"}]

var newarray = array.sort((a, b) => {
  const date = new Date(a.dueDate) - new Date(b.dueDate);
  const isComplete = a.isComplete - b.isComplete;

  return isComplete || date ;
})

console.log(newarray);
```